# Create widget displaying a text message depending on the date

Tags: android

I want to create a widget which display a text message depending on the date. My problem is that i do not know how to detect when the system changes date.

My code:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
  MediaPlayer mp = null;// Here int m,n; 
  @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     String action = intent.getAction(); 
     if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)) { // new
       MainActivity().setSunrise(); 
       Toast.makeText(context, "deteced date change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } 

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  int m,n;
  @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     String action = intent.getAction();
     if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)) {
       Toast.makeText(context, "deteced date change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything you have tried ? post your code.

Comment: public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
 MediaPlayer mp = null;// Here
 int m,n;
 
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {
  
    String action = intent.getAction();
       
      
          if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)) 
          {
           
           
          // new MainActivity().setSunrise();
           Toast.makeText(context, "deteced date change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           
          }

Comment: public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
 
 int m,n;
 
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {
  
    String action = intent.getAction();
       
      
          if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)) 
          {
           
           
        
           Toast.makeText(context, "deteced date change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           
          }}}

Comment: i have searched a lot but not getting exact solution which i want.help me

Comment: i want to detect automatic system date change.

Comment: @Bhavik Use the `edit` link under your question to edit and update your question.